# How to GET Request with Cookie After login

Tags: go, web-crawler

I tried to get some resp.Body of jadwalURL. jadwalURL can be access after login, so I add the Cookie header to the request. But Sadly the response is not quite that I want (response is home page). I tried this similiar flow with Postman. and I got the jadwalURL body as i wanted. Is there anything wrong with my code? I still dont get the solution after 3 hours searching.

```golang
func main() {
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("username", username)
    data.Set("password", password)
    client := &http.Client{}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, loginURL, strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    resp, _ := client.Do(r)
    cookie := resp.Cookies()
    fmt.Println(cookie)
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, jadwalURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{
        Name:   cookie[0].Name,
        Value:  cookie[0].Value,
        Domain: domainURL,
        Path:   "/",
    })

    jadwalResp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(nil)
    }
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jadwalReq.Body)
    jadwalResp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you have this problem I just change create a newClient the problem is i tried to make request with client.

```
newClient := &http.Client{}
// then
jadwalResp, err := newClient.Do(req)
```